# Fonts are garbled, distorted in LIbreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I have been having difficulties with fonts and word spacing in LibreOffice Writer.  The letters overlap.  Also, LO Writer doesn't type at the print size it displays (i.e. it types at 30 pt. when 12pt is indicated.)  How would I change LO Writer to space characters properly and type at the indicated font size?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Some details first, what OS/release, are you using a snap or deb packaged version of LibreOffice, or where was it installed for your unspecified OS/release.